# type 'X' is not assignable to type 'Y' in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sorry for asking this question ,but I need someone's help to fix it .

What I trying is I have a model class in my Angular 4 app,I want to assign the type to a property in component but it shows the error as

error :

```
[ts]
Type '{ gender: null; mTitle: null; mFName: null; mLName: null; mEmail: null; mPassword: null; mDOB: Da...' is not assignable to type 'User'.
  Types of property 'mDOB' are incompatible.
    Type 'DateConstructor' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
      Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'DateConstructor'.
(property) CreateaccountComponent.mUser: User
```

User.ts (model class)

```
export class User {
    gender :string;
    mTitle: string;
    mFName: string;
    mLName: string;
    mEmail: string;
    mPassword: string;
    mDOB: Date;
    mNewsLetter: string;
    mSpecialOffer: string;
}
```

component

```
import { User } from '../../User';

export class CreateaccountComponent implements OnInit {

  mUser: User = {
    gender: null,
    mTitle: null,
    mFName: null,
    mLName: null,
    mEmail: null,
    mPassword: null,
    mDOB: Date,
    mNewsLetter: null,
    mSpecialOffer: null,
  };

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
  submitForm(userForm: NgForm): void {
  }
}
```

here mUser is underlined as red and showing the above error .

can anyone help me to fix this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the initialization stage you assign to `mDOB` property the function with name `Date` (so why error is about *`Type 'DateConstructor' is not assignable to type 'Date'`*.), not it's instance. Either assign a default date or `null`.

```
mUser: User = {
    gender: null,
    mTitle: null,
    mFName: null,
    mLName: null,
    mEmail: null,
    mPassword: null,
    mDOB: new Date, // <----- new Date or null
    mNewsLetter: null,
    mSpecialOffer: null,
  };
```

Comment: Please up vote this question ,my account is in critical state (about to block)@SurenSrapyan